# Understanding part of Linux Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax

I´m trying to understand a Linux Bash Script. The aim of the script is to limit the access to server services only for some dyndns users (by use of ufw rules). Part of the script:

```
ALLOWEDUSERS="client1.dyndns.org client2.dyndns.org"

for host in $ALLOWEDUSERS ; do
    ip=`host $host | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       ufw allow proto tcp from $ip to any
    fi
done
```

okay

```
for host in $ALLOWEDUSERS ; do
```

is clear, it loops through ALLOWEDUSERS,

as far as I understand

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

checks if the command executed before is true (if so the ufw rule is added)

but how does the rest of the snippet

```
ip=`host $host | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
```

checks if the client ip is the one from the allowed dyndns account?

thanks a lot for your help,

tony

Comment: This script is badly written and probably broken. Why waste time with it?

Comment: Hi Barmar "Why waste time with it?" - For learning purpose.

Comment: The programmer apparently thought he was checking the exit status of the `host` command, which is `0` if the hostname lookup is successful. But it's actually checking the exit status of `cut`, because the status of a pipeline is the status of the last command. So it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @tBook I didn't write that.

Comment: @tBook Then learn from other better written scripts. This thing is a bug nest. `cut` will always return true in this case, hence `ufw` will always run. Oh dear.

Comment: Try running `host $host` on its own, and then `host $host | cut -d ' ' -f 4`, that should give you a better understanding of what's going on. (obviously, replace $host with one of the ALLOWEDUSERS)

Comment: hi JB, good idea. will try that.

Comment: @Barmar, I get the point with cut, but if I test it, the rules are working? Only the Dyndns Users have access ???

Comment: When `host` fails, `$ip` will be an empty string, and the syntax of the firewall rule that it tries to add will be invalid.

Comment: Bang! thanks! I think I got it, the part of the Script doesn´t check the clients ip. it checks  with the host command if client.dyndns ... gives a valid ip, if so the rule will also be working, because  the rule will have a valid ip instead of an empty string ....

Comment: @Barmar. May I ask you one last thing. You said "bug nest". Do you see a security risk by using this? as mentioned, I get the point, its not clean code – but its working. I don´t see the scenario where someone could get around this (and get access to services).

Comment: host='verybadhost'
 ip=`host $host | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
 echo $?
0  , $? is exit status of cut which is zero

Comment: I never said "bug nest". gniourf_gniourf did.

Comment: right, sorry for this …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is essentially equivalent to:

```
ALLOWEDUSERS="client1.dyndns.org client2.dyndns.org"

for host in $ALLOWEDUSERS ; do
    ip=`host $host | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
    ufw allow proto tcp from $ip to any
done
```

The `if` in the original script was checking the result of `cut`, not `host`, and it was always successful, so it served no useful purpose.

When the DynDNS hostname is valid, a rule will be added to the firewall to allow it.

When the hostname isn't found, the `host` command prints:

```
Host clientN.dyndns.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

so `$ip` will be `found:`. This will try to do:

```
ufw allow proto tcp from found: to any
```

Since that's not a valid firewall rule, I expect it will be ignored and an error message issued.

If you want to do what the script was apparently trying to do, it should be:

```
ALLOWEDUSERS="client1.dyndns.org client2.dyndns.org"

for host in $ALLOWEDUSERS ; do
    hostresult=`host $host`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        ip=`echo "$hostresult" | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
        ufw allow proto tcp from $ip to any
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks for this extensive helpful answer! thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't realy check anything.

The output from `host $host` is anything like
`$host has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

For example:

```
$ host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
```

Afterwards `cut -d ' ' -f 4` isolates the fourth part, which is the ip address. This is used as the ip address for the `ufw` command.